# backbone.js modify specific fields of model after fetch the collection

Tags: backbone.js

```
var items=[{"endsAt": "2013-05-26T07:00:00Z","id": 1,"name": "Niuniu1"},
{"endsAt": "2013-05-26T07:00:00Z","id": 2,"name": "Niuniu2"}]

ItemModel=Backbone.Model.extend({});
ItemCollection=Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model:ItemModel,
    url: '...',

    parse: function(response) { 
      return response.items;
    }

})
```

If I have a series of data like items, when I build model, for each model, it's endAt will be "2013-05-26T07:00:00Z".  Where can I modify the model or data process so it will actually be "2013-05-26"?

I could do a foreach loop inside collection to process the date, but I'm wondering if there is a better pracitce like to do a parse inside the model?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The practice I use is the one you said you've thought about - implementing a custom parse on the model. As the documentation states, it will be called for you after a sync. See here: http://backbonejs.org/#Model-parse

```
ItemModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    parse: function(response,options) {
       //perform your work on 'response', 
       //    return the attributes this model should have.
    };
})
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you have 2 options here

- Implement a custom `parse` method inside your model
- Implement the `initialize` method inside your model

Both of them don't have any problems, I did 2 ways in several projects, and they work well

Comment: Will implementing an initialize method help for the case of fetch, which will reset the model's state, but not reinitialize?

Comment: I think he also means when adding new models which uses `initialize`